# What do these GPU parameters mean?

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, gpu, hyper-v

I was able to get some GPU virtualization working by [following the steps shown on this site](https://forum.level1techs.com/t/2-gamers-1-gpu-with-hyper-v-gpu-p-gpu-partitioning-finally-made-possible-with-hyperv/172234).

However, I do not understand what any of the values mean.

For example, I get the same output when running the resource checking script:

```
TotalVRAM               : 1000000000
AvailableVRAM           : 1000000000
MinPartitionVRAM        : 0
MaxPartitionVRAM        : 1000000000
OptimalPartitionVRAM    : 1000000000
TotalCompute            : 1000000000
```

But what does `1000000000` mean? If it was bytes, it seems strange for compute and RAM to be equal.

Also when looking at the script, although it works for me, I don't know how to modify it. e.g. what is`-MinPartitionVRAM 1` and `-MaxPartitionVRAM 11`? Is it 1GB and 11GB?

```
$vm = "ENTER YOUR VM NAME HERE"
Remove-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm
Add-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MinPartitionVRAM 1
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MaxPartitionVRAM 11
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -OptimalPartitionVRAM 10
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MinPartitionEncode 1
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MaxPartitionEncode 11
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -OptimalPartitionEncode 10
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MinPartitionDecode 1
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MaxPartitionDecode 11
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -OptimalPartitionDecode 10
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MinPartitionCompute 1
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -MaxPartitionCompute 11
Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter -VMName $vm -OptimalPartitionCompute 10
Set-VM -GuestControlledCacheTypes $true -VMName $vm
Set-VM -LowMemoryMappedIoSpace 1Gb -VMName $vm
Set-VM -HighMemoryMappedIoSpace 32GB -VMName $vm
Start-VM -Name $vm
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the official documentation at Learn/Windows/PowerShell/Reference/Hyper-V/Set-VMGpuPartitionAdapter

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/set-vmgpupartitionadapter?view=windowsserver2022-ps

It says:

> -MaxPartitionVRAM is the maximum VRAM in **bytes** supported by the host GPU. This is defined by the manufacturer's driver.

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the accuracy of what's being reported out -- I am not 100% sure of that.

I have an EVGA RTX 3090 XC3 (24 GB of VRAM) but when I run Get-VMGpuPartitionAdapter in PowerShell as Administrator, it says that my RTX 3090 only have 1000000000 bytes of max VRAM.

So, I'm not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).